# Why isn't the addEventListener working when I drop picture in zone?

Tags: javascript

I'm making "Drag and Drop File Upload". But Now I have a problem.

As you see that ,When I drag something on "drop-zone", The border-style become solid.

Then When I leave my mouse from "drop-zone", The border-style become dashed.

The problem is when I drop something on "drop-zone", It doesn't come back to dashed.

What's my problem with the code?

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".drop-zone__input").forEach(inputElement => {
  let dropZoneElement = inputElement.closest(".drop-zone");

  dropZoneElement.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
    dropZoneElement.classList.add("drop-zone__over");
  });

  ["dragleave", "dragend"].forEach(type => {
    dropZoneElement.addEventListener(type, e => {
      dropZoneElement.classList.remove("drop-zone__over");
    });
  });

  dropZoneElement.addEventListener("drop", e => {
    dropZoneElement.classList.remove("drop-zone__over");
  });
});
```

```css
.drop-zone {
  border: 5px dashed plum;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-zone__over {
  border-style: solid;
}

.drop-zone__thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drop-zone__thumb::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(114, 113, 113);
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.drop-zone__input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-zone">
  <span class="drop-zone__prompt">Click here or Drag a picture</span>
  <!-- <div class="drop-zone__thumb" data-label="tesdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsxt.txt"></div> -->
  <input type="file" name="myFile" class="drop-zone__input">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does adding `e.preventDefault()` fix it in your original code?

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".drop-zone__input").forEach(inputElement => {
  let dropZoneElement = inputElement.closest(".drop-zone");

  dropZoneElement.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
  
   e.preventDefault(); // HERE
   
    dropZoneElement.classList.add("drop-zone__over");
  });

  ["dragleave", "dragend"].forEach(type => {
    dropZoneElement.addEventListener(type, e => {
      dropZoneElement.classList.remove("drop-zone__over");
    });
  });

  dropZoneElement.addEventListener("drop", e => {
  
    e.preventDefault(); // HERE
    
    dropZoneElement.classList.remove("drop-zone__over");
  });
});
```

```css
.drop-zone {
  border: 5px dashed plum;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-zone__over {
  border-style: solid;
}

.drop-zone__thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drop-zone__thumb::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(114, 113, 113);
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.drop-zone__input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-zone">
  <span class="drop-zone__prompt">Click here or Drag a picture</span>
  <!-- <div class="drop-zone__thumb" data-label="tesdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsxt.txt"></div> -->
  <input type="file" name="myFile" class="drop-zone__input">
</div>
```

Comment: Why should I add "e.preventDefault()" to "dragover"?
I thought It s enough adding  "e.preventDefault()" to "drop"

Comment: I mean, you could "not" add it, but it will stop working.